# How to solve ODE

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

Solve the DE:

$$2y^2y''+2y(y')^2=1$$

Is it possible to solve this by implicit substitution i.e. let $v = y'$ and thus

$$\frac{dv}{dy}v = \frac{1-2yv^2}{2y^2}$$

by the chain rule. And then from here let $z = \frac{v}{y}$? What if $y=0$?

Comment: $y\equiv 0$ is not a solution and since it does not satisfy the equation even pointwise, I think that the state $y=0$ cannot be reached in a finite time.

Comment: @bartgol Ah, so not an issue for the substitution?

Comment: how about you substitute $v^2/2 = F$. The LHS reads $v*dv/dy \equiv dF/dy$? You solve $F'(x)=(1-2xF)/(2x^2)$ (where $F=dv/dy^2$ and $x\equiv y$).

Comment: @Chip how is that solved?

Comment: Well, you do the substitution *assuming* $y\neq 0$. If you find that your solution actually hits $y=0$ at a finite time, then the maximal interval of existence of the solution ends there. Most likely, assuming it is possible to get $y(t_M)=0$, you will get that either $y'$ or $y''$ (or both) are unbounded near $t_M$.

Comment: @bartgol Notwithstanding the interval of existence, is this a correct method to solve this ode?

Comment: @deret: well, your new ODE reads $F' + \frac{1}{x}F-\frac{1}{2x^2}=0$, which you solve using the method of variation of constants if I recall...

Comment: @deret: btw, what are your initial conditions?

Comment: I think so. But I don't see how $z=v/y$ is going to help...

Comment: @Chip no i.c. given

Comment: @bartgol does it not then become $$\frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{1}{2y^3} -\frac{3z}{y}$$?

Comment: Uh, I haven't done the calculations. However, assuming yours are, you can solve the last equation, but you are only going to find $y'=F(y)$, which is still a differential equation that has to be integrated. It may be simple though, I don't know.

Comment: I don't know how this could help but defining $y=\sqrt z$ leads to $z''\sqrt z=1$

Answer (score 2):

It has been observed in the comments that the equation can be rewritten in terms of the derivatives of $y^2$, namely as
$$
y(y^2)''=1
$$
Multiplication with $4y'$ allows one integration to
$$
((y^2)')^2=4y+C
$$
So it remains to integrate (using a different constant $C$)
$$
\frac{yy'}{\sqrt{C\pm y}}=1.
$$

Comment: This is nice and easy to inetegrate !

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y(x) \sim x^\alpha$ satisfies the ODE. After substitution, a 2nd order equation is found for $\alpha$. This gives you the two solutions.

Comment: How do you note $y \sim x^\alpha$?

Comment: You notice how the terms in your equation are somewhat homogeneous with regard to a $x^\alpha$ solution: every time you differentiate, the rest of the factors compensate the smaller power of the argument following differentiation. Or you can just try it (is fast), since it is part of the ODE exercises to use such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$2y^2y''+2y(y')^2=1$$ let us use the reverse relations between derivatives, that is to say, $$y'_x=\frac 1  {x'_y}\qquad , \qquad y''_x=-\frac{x''_y}{{x'_y}^3}$$ and replace in the original equation. This leads to $$\frac{2 y}{x'^2}-\frac{2 y^2 x''}{x'^3}=1$$ and the function $x$ disappeared.

So, now, define $x'=t$ which gives $$\frac{2 y}{t^2}-\frac{2 y^2 t'}{t^3}=1$$ Now, let $t=\frac 1{\sqrt z}$ leads to $$2yz+y^2z'=1\implies (y^2z)'=1\implies y^2z=y+C_1\implies z=\frac 1y+\frac{C_1}{y^2}$$ Back to $t$ $$t=x'=\pm \frac y {\sqrt{y+C_1}}$$ and a last integration leads to $$x=\pm\frac{2}{3} (y-2 C_1) \sqrt{C_1+y}+C_2$$

**I must underline that the same solution is obtained faster using LutzL's answer.**